# compare metabolites of baseline and postbaseline for same people

Tags: cbind, isolate

I have two datasets. One is baseline and the other is post baseline

1st one and 2nd one contains same people.

1st table: Baseline

| People | metabolite 1 | metabolite298 | metabolite 333 | metabolite999 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 989.00 | 2.33 | 198297.09 |  |
| ABC2 | 7675.99 | 5.67 | 197233.45 |  |

2nd table: Postbaseline

| People | metabolite298 | metabolite333 | metabolite4 | metabolite78 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 97.11 | 5763.00 | 65645 | 122 |
| ABC2 | 98 | 777 | 121 | 2 |

Now I want to have a table where I will have a ratio of postbaseline/baseline of the common metabolites only.

So I want to have a table like this.

| People | Metabolite298 | metabolite333 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 97.11/2.33 | 5763.00/198297.09 |  |
| ABC2 | 98/5.67 | 777/197233.45 |  |

Can you please provide any code for this?

I tried to do cbind but I could not isolate the common ones only. Can you please help me out with it?